# How to access the "right" scope from inside a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to order the table rows in several places. As there's just one "main" table shown, I've decided to use a rather global variable `$scope.n.order` (where `n` is my collection of **n**on-important **n**on-persisted variables).

The rather repetitive approach works fine:

```
<th ng-click="n.order=['created','id']">Created</tr>
...
<tr ng-repeat="x in m.items | orderBy: n.order">
```

As I want to add some `order` class to the sorting column (and maybe more such things), I want to create a corresponding directive so that I can write

```
<th my-order=created>Created</th>
```

instead (no big win, I know). My only problem is that the directive gets no access to the proper `$scope`... in debugger I can see that I would have to access `$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent` or alike. What's the proper way to get on it? I don't know the name of the controller, so I can't use `require`. I only know that it's sort of "my main" controller (responsible for the whole page).

---

Upon a request I'm adding some code, but I'm afraid it explains nothing as the problem is the access to the proper scope only. The proper scope could be defined as the one having the variable I need. ;)

```
.directive('myOrder', function($location) {
    function link($scope, element, attr) {
        var list = $scope.myOrder.split(/,/);
        element.on('click', function() {
            $scope.n.order = list;
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        // I've tried also `scope: false` and leaving it out and whatever...
        scope: {
            myOrder: "@", // this works
            n: "=" // this doesn't as `n` is many scopes away
        },
        link: link
    };
```

---

Actually, my last sentence brought me to a "solution". Follow parent till the proper scope. It works but feels totally hacky...

Comment: some more code would be good to work on

Comment: (1) Do not forget to add `$scope.$apply()` in the `element.on` handler. (2) How are you specifying the `n` scope parameter and it doesn't work? From `<th my-order=created>Created</th>`, `n` is *NOT* defined - and you cannot expect it to work! Something like `<th my-order="created" n="n">Created</th>` may do it...

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos 1. Thanks for `$scope.$apply()`. 2. The variable named `$scope.n` *always* exists in *some* enclosing scope as I'm always creating it in each "page-controller". 3. `n="n"` would possibly create a new variable, anyway, I want to keep the directive use as short as possible.

Comment: In your code above, `scope: { ..., n: "="}` you *are* creating a new `n` variable in the *isolated* scope, that is bound to an expression of the outer scope. If that expression is `n="n"`, the isolated `n` is bound to the outer `n` which is what you want (I guess). Anyway, if you could provide a fiddle/plunk, things would probably be clearer.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos You're right, there's `scope: { ..., n: "="}`, which I forgot as it didn't work. There is `n` in some far outer scope, but not in the enclosing one. I'll try to extract the problem in fiddle/plunk, but it's not easy (when done in the straightforward way, the problem simply disappears).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Thank you for your help. It was mostly confusion on my side, not it's clear and I could answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see I was confusing things (again). I should have decided if I wanted an isolated scope, or inheriting, or none at all. I actually need no scope, as my directive used as

```
<th my-order=created>Created</th>
```

should reach out to the scope of the enclosing element for a hash called `n` and set

```
`n.myOrder = "created"
```

This is hacky and not reusable in case of multiple such orders, but OK for me as there's always up to one master table to be sorted, so I'm employing a convention for the sort column variable name (passing this name as an argument is the obvious extension to come when needed). An isolated scope is fine, all I need is

```
  $scope.$parent.n.order = list;
```

Using a debugged I couldn't see `$scope.$parent` there, and this lead me astray. In fact, it doesn't exist, but it gets prototypically inherited, so everything's fine.